# Native Android DatePicker with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, datefield

I am currently building a web based application and would like to use the native Android date picker for a field.  I have looked into using PhoneGap but it seems to be more than I need for my project. Is there anyway to invoke the date picker field with basic JavaScript?

Also, I am not looking to use jQuery Mobile as the CSS for it completely disables my current look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android you cannot inwoke the native datepicker from a web app (input type="date" would be the correct way, which is supported on iOS > 5).

I recommend using [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com), which is a javascript datepicker (and not just datepicker) plugin, which has themes to make it look like the native date picker.

Comment: Mobiscroll is actually the piece I chose.

Comment: seriously, Google!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the answer to your question is "no".  PhoneGap works by having native libraries for each platform that are accessible through a Javascript API -- without the native libraries, I don't think you will be able to invoke the date picker field.

That said, PhoneGap is an open source project, so you can always analyze their source, and see what would be necessary to implement it.  The PhoneGap code for Android is here:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android

Answer (score 1):

I googled the PhoneGap datapicker plugin, and came across this

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker

I think this is what you are looking for, but I did not test it personally.

Comment: I've looked into it but it seems to be a bit more than I need.  I looked through setting up PhoneGap and it seems to be a bit complex.  From my perspective it's more work than it's worth to get one small piece of functionality.  I may be over-complicating the setup and if I am some guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: The setup of PhoneGap could be confusing. The recent transit from PhoneGap to Cordova makes it worse. Can you let me know where you are at setting up? It is easier to help if there is a specific problem.

Comment: Well I never actually started setting it up.  I just read through the guide to do so.  I ended up settling on a JS plugin that allows me to use a customizable datepicker.  It's the easy way to go as the deadline for delivery is rapidly approaching.  I'm going to readdress this problem in the next sprint and see if I can get PhoneGap functioning.